# Multiple Polygons display on Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, maps, coordinates, polygon

I have a google map where I can draw circles, rectangles and polygons and then save their coordinates in a database with a name. Now I want every time the map gets loaded all the saved regions to be displayed. I have managed this with the circles and rectangles(fixed number of coordinates) but I'm stuck on how I will display the polygon. I am getting the standard method of displaying from this google triangle example: [Polygon Arrays](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polygon-arrays).
Everything is great until I reach this part:

```
var triangleCoords = [
        {lat: 25.774, lng: -80.190},
        {lat: 18.466, lng: -66.118},
        {lat: 32.321, lng: -64.757}
    ];
```

I have saved polygons of different sizes, so every time the loop of displaying runs, I need to put into triangleCoords different number of lats and lngs. I tried it using the triangleCoords as a table but it went terribly wrong:

```
                    var j=1;
                    var k;
                    for (k = 0; k < (coo.length)/2 ; k++ ){
                        var triangleCoords[k] = [
                            {lat: coo[j], lng: coo[j+1]}
                        ];
                        j+=2;
                    }
```

It could be something very simple but I am not long into programming and now I am getting deeper! Could you help? Any hint on where should I look? Some example code? Thanks in advance!

Here is some more code, does that help?

```
<?php  
                $result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM allplaces WHERE user_id = '$userid' "); 

                  $coordinates = array();
                  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) {     
                    $coordinates[] = $row['coordinates']; 
                  } 
                ?>
var coordinates = new Array();
    <?php 
                for ($i=0;$i<count($coordinates); $i++)
                {
                    echo "coordinates[$i]='".$coordinates[$i]."';\n";
                }
?>
var i;
    for (i = 0; i < coordinates.length; i++) {  

                    var str = coordinates[i];
                var coo = str.split(";"); //first cell of coo is empty

if ( type[i] == 1 ){            //polygon

                    // Define the LatLng coordinates for the polygon's path.

   --> [code here that fills the triangleCoords each time, where triangleCoords must have the form that is given in the first Code Sample]

                    // Construct the polygon.
                    var bermudaTriangle = new google.maps.Polygon({
                      paths: triangleCoords,
                      strokeColor: '#FF0000',
                      strokeOpacity: 0.8,
                      strokeWeight: 2,
                      fillColor: '#FF0000',
                      fillOpacity: 0.35
                    });
                    bermudaTriangle.setMap(map); 
}
}
```

Comment: Please provide an [mcve] that demonstrates the issue, including a sample of the data.

Comment: I added some more code, does that help?

Comment: The PHP is not particularly useful without your database.  A [mcve] would be better (the HTML served to the browser might give you a starting point).

Comment: I dont understand what you ask, I think my question is very clear with the data I provided. How can I fill the triangleCoords table in every loop with different number of lats and lngs? I could do without the code if someone could explain the way I should work or on what direction should I search. I maybe dont search it the right way, even a right search word would be helpful!

Comment: What do those coordinates that you are trying to fill the `trianglCoords` var iable with look like?  I can guess, but that would waste my time if I was wrong. You have a sample of what you want the result to be, but not what the input data looks like.  Did you look at [the link](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) I provided?

Comment: Thanks for trying to help! I reached the solution, I posted it as an answer. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made it work! What I needed was to push into the array every new point of the polygon. It was simple but I hadnt in mind the use of "push". The code follows!

```
var bermudaTriangle = [];
var j;
var k=1;
for (j=0; j < (coo.length)/2 ; j++){
    bermudaTriangle.push(new google.maps.LatLng(coo[k],coo[k+1]));
    k+=2;
}
```